# Combine MongoDB Queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Below is an example of a document in my MongoDB collection:

```
{
  "countries": ["IN", "US", "UK"],
  "regions": ["North", "South", "East", "West"],
  "types": ["A", "C"],
  "doc": {
    "prop" : "value"
  }
}
```

Based to input parameters and session info, I have to query countries, regions and types. My JavaScript code to for querying by country and region would like this:

```
if(inputCountry && !inputRegion) {
  db.collection.find({countries: inputCountry}, callback);
} else if(!inputCountry && inputRegion) {
  db.collection.find({regions: inputRegion}, callback);
} else if(inputCountry && inputRegion)
  db.collection.find({countries: inputCountry, regions: inputRegion}, callback);
} else {
  db.collection.find({}, callback);
}
```

As you see I'm already having 4 if-else conditions for countries and regions. When I also query by type this would get more complex due to various combinations and get very error-prone.

Is there a way to avoid doing this and can we combine the mongo queries?

Comment: Where are these input parameters coming from? If they are from the `req.query` or `req.params` object then there is a way you can structure your query without using the conditional statements.

Comment: two are from req.query and one is from req.session. how to do this without conditionals?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript `if` and create an object as follow.

```
// The condition in the query
var condition = {};

// If exists, add to the condition
if (inputCountry) {
    condition.countries = inputCountry;
}
if (inputRegion) {
    condition.regions = inputRegion;
}

// Execute query
db.collection.find(condition, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the query based on the conditions and do find once everything is done:-

```
var findQuery ={};
if(inputCountry && !inputRegion) {
   findQuery = {countries: inputCountry};
} 
else if(!inputCountry && inputRegion) {
   findQuery = {regions: inputRegion};
} 
else if(inputCountry && inputRegion)
   findQuery = {countries: inputCountry, regions: inputRegion};
}
```

Now do the find.

```
db.collection.find(findQuery).toArray(function(err, result)    
{
      console.log(result); //Array of objects    
});
```